# R conditional apply does not work equally for all records

Tags: r, conditional-statements, apply

I have the below dataframe. Change_Month signifies the month before which all values for an Adv fall under N category and from that month onwards under V category.

```
Adv_Code Change_Month Change_Dt     April   May June    July    August  September   October November    December    January     February    March
A201    April           7/4/2017    0       0   0       1       0       0           0       0           0           0           0           0
A198    April           7/4/2017    1       1   0       0       3       0           0       0           0           0           0           0
S1212   May             16/04/2017  0       0   0       0       0       0           0       0           0           0           0           1
S1213   January         4/1/2018    1       0   0       1       1       1           1       0           1           1           2           1
```

So for A201, all values will fall under V category. Similarly for A198.
For S1212, April value will come under N category and remaining under V.
Similarly, for S1213, April - December will be under N category and January - March under V.

Hence, the expected output is:

```
Adv_Code Change_Month Change_Dt     April   May June    July    August  September   October November    December    January     February    March N_OPN V_OPN
A201    April           7/4/2017    0       0   0       1       0       0           0       0           0           0           0           0       0   1
A198    April           7/4/2017    1       1   0       0       3       0           0       0           0           0           0           0       0   5
S1212   May             16/04/2017  0       0   0       0       0       0           0       0           0           0           0           1       0   1
S1213   January         4/1/2018    1       0   0       1       1       1           1       0           1           1           2           1       6   4
```

I tried with the below code:

```
col <- 4 #Column number from where the months start

df[c("N_OPN", "V_OPN")] <- t(apply(df, 1, function(x) {
  inds <- grep(x[["Change_Month"]], names(x))
  if (as.numeric(substr(x["Change_Dt"], 1, 2)) > 15)
    c(sum(as.numeric(x[col:pmax(col, inds - 1)])), 
      sum(as.numeric(x[inds:ncol(df)])))
  else
    c(sum(as.numeric(x[col:inds])), 
      sum(as.numeric(x[pmin(ncol(df), inds + 1):ncol(df)])))
}))
```

However this gives :

```
Adv_Code Change_Month Change_Dt     April   May June    July    August  September   October November    December    January     February    March N_OPN V_OPN
A201    April           7/4/2017    0       0   0       1       0       0           0       0           0           0           0           0       0   1
A198    April           7/4/2017    1       1   0       0       3       0           0       0           0           0           0           0       1   5
S1212   May             16/04/2017  0       0   0       0       0       0           0       0           0           0           0           1       0   1
S1213   January         4/1/2018    1       0   0       1       1       1           1       0           1           1           2           1       7   3
```

I am not sure why exactly this is happening.
Can someone please help me in this?

Below is the code to reproduce the dataframe:

```
df <- structure(list(Adv_Code = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L,4L), .Label = c("A198","A201", "S1212","S1213"), class = "factor"),
                        Change_Dt = structure(c(2L,3L, 1L,1L), .Label = c("07/04/2017", "07/04/2017", "16/04/2017","4/1/2018"), class = "factor"), 
                        Change_Month = structure(1:4, .Label = c("April", "April","May","January"), class = "factor"), April = c(0L, 1L, 0L,1L), 
                        May = c(0L, 1L, 0L,0L), June = c(0L, 0L, 0L,0L), July = c(1L, 0L,0L,1L),
                        August = c(0L, 3L, 0L,1L), September = c(0L,0L, 0L,1L), October = c(0L, 0L, 0L,1L), November = c(0L,0L, 0L,0L), 
                        December = c(0L, 0L, 0L,1L), January = c(0L,0L, 0L,1L), February = c(0L, 0L, 0L,2L), March = c(0L,0L, 1L,1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option with `for` loop is

```
df1 <- df[4:ncol(df)]
j1 <- match(df$Change_Month, names(df1))
N_OPN <- numeric(nrow(df1))
V_OPN <- numeric(nrow(df1))
for(i in seq_len(nrow(df1))) {
        j2 <- j1[i] -1
        N_OPN[i] <- if(j2 == 0) 0 else sum(df1[i, seq_len(j2)])
        V_OPN[i] <- sum(df1[i, (j1[i]:ncol(df1))])
  }

df[c("N_OPN", "V_OPN")] <- list(N_OPN, V_OPN)
df
#  Adv_Code  Change_Dt Change_Month April May June July August September October November December January
#1     A201 07/04/2017        April     0   0    0    1      0         0       0        0        0       0
#2     A198 16/04/2017        April     1   1    0    0      3         0       0        0        0       0
#3    S1212 07/04/2017          May     0   0    0    0      0         0       0        0        0       0
#4    S1213 07/04/2017      January     1   0    0    1      1         1       1        0        1       1
#  February March N_OPN V_OPN
#1        0     0     0     1
#2        0     0     0     5
#3        0     1     0     1
#4        2     1     6     4
```

Comment: It gives error in the if condition:
Error in if ((j2 == 0) == TRUE) 0 else sum(df1[i, seq_len(j2)]) : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Comment: @ShuvayanDas  Not for me.  It is based on the example dput you showed

Comment: @ShuvayanDas  Are you using the same data as the dput data you showed?

Comment: Hey @akrun.. Sorry.. The data i have contains OPN appended to month names as April_OPN etc. Without that, the code works fine. Thank you!

Comment: @ShuvayanDas  In that case remove the `suffix` with `names(df1) <- sub("_.*", "", names(df1))` and then apply the code